# How to Open an Excel Document from Share Point by Internet Explorer using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Am new to VBA & trying to learn as I go. Am currently stuck with an Issue here which I need some help.

Am trying to open an Excel workbook(`Test.xlsx`) from the share point using Internet Explorer. Once the File is opened, I would like to close IE.  Then copy few Sheets from the Workbook, copy/Move it to a new Workbook & close the original Workbook. 
I searched a lot in Google & came with below codes which works OK if I run it separately, but If I combine with my original program (which I manged to generate by recording Macros) it gives an Error message 'Run-time error'9': Subscript out of range'which when I debug will highlight my Error Handler Code `(Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False)`.

I really cant understand the mistake here.
Can someone please help me with the correct codes here.

Basically my requirement is to open an Excel Workbook from Share point(`"URL/TEST.xlsx"`) using Internet Explorer(in a new window),close IE window & then to copy/move few sheets from the original Workbook(Test.xlsx) to new Workbook, close the original workbook(Test.xlsx) & make amendments in the new workbook(Book##).

Can someone please help me with the codes here.

Below are the codes I managed to get from Google/Internet.

```
Sub OpenIE()

  Dim objIE As Object

  Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  objIE.Navigate "URL/TEST.xlsx"

  objIE.Visible = True**

On Error GoTo My_Error_Handler

    Windows("Test.xlsx").Visible = True

On Error GoTo My_Error_Handler

    Sheets(Array("Stats", "Mtx")).Select

    Sheets("Mtx").Activate

    Sheets(Array("Stats", "Mtx")).Copy

    Sheets("Mtx").Select
    '
'
'
'
' so on 
'
'
My_Error_Handler:

    Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    MsgBox "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description, vbCritical

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not open the file directly in excel instead of using IE? E.g. `Workbooks.Open("http://server.company.com/path/Test.xlsx")`

Comment: Thanks Tim. Tried to open the file directly using below code which came with Run Time Error; 

     Dim strFilePath As String
     strFilePath = "URL/TEST.XLSX"
     ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (strFilePath)

So I thought I'll try using IE, which might work better.
As I said earlier, am new to this world & trying to learn as much as possible from the experts.

Comment: Excel should have no problem directly opening a file from a URL

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SP()
Application.Workbooks.Open "http://123/Testing/Test.xlsx"
End Sub
```

Or if you want to automatically check it out too

```
Sub SP()

fil = "http://123/Testing/Test.xlsx" 
If Application.Workbooks.CanCheckOut(fil) Then 
Application.Workbooks.CheckOut fil 
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fil) 
End If

End Sub
```